# Deploy Angular-cli project to nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, production-environment

I'm trying to deploy an angular-cli project to nginx and i got a problem that css/js failed to load,where i should copy the dist files in nginx folder?

Comment: Make sure you put the project in root with baseUrl="/".

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: I think they mean add this `<base href="/">` to your `index.html` file, I think it goes in the `head`

Answer (score 0):

There could be one of the possibility, that's why you are getting problem/error to load assets:

- Wrong base href in index.html head tag
- Wrong --base-href value while ng build command
- Wrong nginx configuration(i.e. server root OR server location /)

Here is the solution:

Suppose you want to deploy your angular app at HOST: `http://example.com` and PORT: `8080`
Note - HOST and PORT might be different in your case.

Make sure you have `<base href="/">` in you index.html head tag.

1. Firstly, go to your angular repo (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld) path at your machine.
2. Then build /dist for your production server using the following command:

   ng build --prod --base-href http://example.com:8080
3. Now copy /dist (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld/dist) folder from your machine's angular repo to the remote machine where you want to host your production server.
4. Now login to your remote server and add following nginx server configuration.

   ```
   server {

       listen 8080;

       server_name http://example.com;

       root /path/to/your/dist/location;

       # eg. root /home/admin/helloWorld/dist

       index index.html index.htm;

       location / {

           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

           # This will allow you to refresh page in your angular app. Which will not give error 404.

       }

   }
   ```
5. Now restart nginx.
6. That's it !! Now you can access your angular app at http://example.com:8080

Hope it will be helpful.